# call standard function mid()

Tags: function, vbscript

How can I call `mid()` with complete path?

Sample:

```
a = class.mid("bv",1,1)
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_mid.asp

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is : I have a object with the name MID and it's for that I  want to call with the complete path.

Comment: Simply avoid naming variables, procedures and constants to names that could be interchanged or confused with _intrinsic_ names of functions, methods, properties etc.

Comment: That was the best solution, but...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `mid` in square brackets:

```vb
a = class.[mid]("bv",1,1)
```

This feature is called *bracket identifier*, and allows using identifiers with spaces, non-ASCII characters, or identifiers whose names are VBScript reserved words. More info:

[VBScript Trivia: Bracket Identifiers and Reserved Word Incompatibilities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/06/10/152831.aspx)
[Identifiers in square brackets](http://www.stealthbot.net/wiki/VBScript_other_features#Identifiers_in_square_brackets)